# Any interesting thesis topic?

Tags: graphics, education

I study Computer Science at Technical University of Lodz (in Poland) with Computer Game and Simulation Technology specialization. I'm going to defend BSc thesis next year and I was wondering what topic I could choose but nothing **really interesting** is coming to my mind.

Maybe You could help me and suggest some subjects related to programming graphics, games or simulations? (or maybe something else that is interesting enough :) ). I would be very grateful for any suggestion!

Comment: I voted up. So somebody voted down for this. Why? I think that this very good question/wiki

Comment: I'm not the voter, but my guess would be that it's subjective, and not a particularly good subjective question either: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Well, just read the question and ignore the subjective (what is interesting) part of it. He is clearly looking for a list like the answer I see below, a list of game technologies that are being pushed further and further now that near photo-realistic rendering has been around.

Comment: He's asking for topics, not a discussion. I think it's a decent question.

Comment: Voted up, because I find it useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few topics come to my mind

- Fluids simulation: Navier-strokes equations. And gpgpu acceleration ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igXZs2oJQcA))
- Fluids rendering - volumetric raycasting ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVRQUD20q6g))
- Volumetric rendering - marching cubes ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk3SvwOEBe8))
- Realtime bokeh rendering ([paper](http://dxp.korea.ac.kr/homewiki/images/f/f5/PG-PointDof-submit.pdf))
- Point based rendering ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSwQUkx4tyk))
- Realtime rain rendering ([paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70320/RealTimeRain_MSTR.pdf))
- Simple raytracer with global ilumination - propably without accelaration structs.

And the best is contact some computer games/graphics/movie company and offer them to create something they need for free. That have only pluses. You will have hard and interesting thesis ( and prototype ) and some experienced advisor from company who will help you. Don't be afraid to do it. Enthusiasm helps very much in this case. (I know it)

Comment: Some of links leads to my projects. I don't want to promote them this silly. Actually there is no reason, I just like them, so I suggested them. :)

Comment: +1 for the contact a company. There is all sorts of stuff out there that have R&D time frames too long for game development schedules to consider spending resources on. Given that you are in Poland I'd think about contacting Crytek. They have a very active R&D department and are fairly local.

Comment: Great answer, notebene! This is exactly what I wanted to hear - the list of possible subjects.
  


First I will send emails with proposition of doing free project to some game/graphics companies and in case of negative replies I will choose between:  
1. "Simple raytracer with global ilumination - propably without accelaration structs."  
2. "Volumetric rendering - marching cubes"  
3. "Fluids rendering - volumetric raycasting"  
because these topics seem to be interesting to me.  

wkerslake, thanks for suggesting me Crytek! This will be one of my target companies for sure.

Comment: @revers I'm happy you like it. Feel free to contact me via e-mail (my profile) for more info/papers/source codes about raytracers and especially about volume raycasting. I'm working on raycasting now for movie renderer - so i can share materials and also some nice volume data - clouds, fires, nebulas etc.

Answer (score 1):

I did pathfinding on arbitrary 3D environments. Admittedly not totally interesting nor innovative, but it was the closest thing to a game-related thesis I managed to negotiate :S

It was a few years ago, though. Now they're talking about having game development as an elective. How times change :(

Answer (score 0):

Inverse kinematics and behaviors ala NaturalMotion.

Comment: Propably too hard for Bsc thesis. Especially behaviors ala naturalmotion.(now i get why mods says that this is argumentative:))

Comment: Well, one brilliant thing about thesis is that they get to define their scope. You don't need to solve a whole problem, but a finite aspect of it.