# Game Research Points

Tags: ai, gpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any interesting thesis topic?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/any-interesting-thesis-topic)

I just wanna know what are the points of research in nowadays games. As I am Teacher Assistant and I must make a master thesis and I wanted to make the Thesis about games and contribution to game society the problem that all my faculty stuff are from old era where word games mean to them cards and chess boards only so they are useless to help me in finding a research point in gaming field

also I know most of research may be in GPU stuffs (Graphics) or in AI stuffs

But when I think I don't know from where to start and how to get a good research point to work on.

So if anyone can help I will be appreciated :)

Comment: See this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/any-interesting-thesis-topic

Comment: nice article but it only reply on half the question the part about graphics not the AI :) also I wanted more stuff, stuffs related to shaders in graphics :)

Comment: The takeaway from that question, is that it was closed as not constructive. Subjective questions such as "What should I do for my thesis" are not a proper fit for the site. There are some people who have some interesting insight into such things in the chatroom however.