# (Realtime-) Global Illumination starting point

Tags: global-illumination

What techniques should someone look at when getting into real time global illumination (for dynamic lighting scenarios)?

It's hard to get a real grip on the different mentioned techniques without knowing anything about the subject. If I wanted to incorporate GI into my graphics engine, where should I start reading as a baseline? Which algorithms are implementable in a reasonable timeframe by someone new (i.e. not a highly specialized algorithm that gains minor performance for months of work) and which are not completely outdated by now (i.e. straight up replaced by something simply prettier and faster)?

Photon mapping seems to come up a lot, and I've read about things like voxel cone tracing and more specific algorithms, e.g. [this technique used in CryEngine 3](http://www.crytek.com/cryengine/presentations/real-time-diffuse-global-illumination-in-cryengine-3). However, knowing next to nothing about the field it's hard to decide where to start.

What general techniques are worth looking into?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for *dynamic* global illumination? There are many well understood and documented algorithms for static (aka precomputed) global illumination, but I get the feeling you are not looking for those.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm specifically looking for global illumination in dynamic lighting scenarios that manages to get interactive frame rates on "decent hardware"(30+, although not restricted to games).

Comment: When I remember correctly, the global illumination paper used a machine learning approach for approximating global illumination with dynamic lights but static scenes. Depending on how you define *dynamic global illumination*, this may not be what you're looking for. Also there are screen space approximations which might be an interesting comparison to normal world or view space algorithms.

Comment: While an interesting topic, this question is essentially a "What to learn next", and doesn't really have a correct answer. Instead, I only see it generating a list of topics (which I believe is exactly what you're after). It's certainly a cool topic, but it's a discussion topic, and likely not a fit for the site.

Comment: @Byte56 Alright, just leave it open for a couple more hours so I get answers :D

Comment: Anyone who would like to answer this question can talk to TravisG in chat :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10194/bachelor-thesis-global-illumination

Comment: Could we modify this question to just ask what the state of the art in dynamic global illumination is? The author can then look and find the answer to his question from the information given while still leaving the answers as (hopefully) a good reference on the topic.

Comment: A question about what the current state of the art is would be highly localized in time.

Comment: 9 upvotes and closed? Are you serious? @Byte56

Comment: @JoshPetrie Perhaps when worded as state of the art, but this question has the potential to have very useful answers and the reason for close seems to be rather superficial.

Comment: Well, to be fair it's only "on hold" :P I'll try to rewrite the question right now to get something more neutrally beneficial for everyone.

Comment: Alright, I tried modifying it a bit. But feel free to edit it yourselves also. I definitely feel like we can create a good starting point for someone looking into the subject here.

Comment: @ashes999 Unfortunately, popular does not mean on topic. [Example A](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/game-development-blogs) [Example 2](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-it-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo). There was agreement with another moderator for putting this on hold. Further example of a [similar question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/any-interesting-thesis-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you look into [my MSc thesis](https://ir.library.dc-uoit.ca/handle/10155/301)?

The result apparently blew too hard for SIGGRAPH to accept (they rejected my paper) and I didn't submit to any other conferences.  But it still presents a good introduction to GI, written in typical bobobobo understandability (actually some sections go into a bit too much depth, but hey).

You'll want to look at section 2.4, which very quickly and with references runs through some of the newer real-time gi algorithms including

- real time ray tracing
- real time radiosity (enlighten/bf3)
- deferred shading and screen space methods (ssdo, ssao)
- precomputed radiance transfer and spherical harmonics

That's all I got in my survey.  Disclaimer that I may have missed something.

Anyway, you really have no hope of implementing all of these in 3 months.  I'd say pick **one** and work with it.  Real-time ray tracing is by far the most exciting to *me*, because it's a true gi method.  Unlike screen space methods, rtrt isn't a "hack" -- it doesn't suffer from weird effects that ssdo does:

[image]

Comment: >Anyway, you really have no hope of implementing all of these in 3 months. I'd say pick one and work with it.< That's disappointing. I'm not sure how I would approach a single algorithm in a manner that's worth a bachelors thesis. I think just implementing it to see how it looks isn't nearly enough. And I don't think I'm capable of coming up with my own improvements on a particular algorithm (just don't know anything about the field). Well at least, I'd like to not risk having to spend 6 more months studying on it.

Comment: Well, speak with your supervisor.  Have you written a raytracer before?  At the core of any of these is usually a raytracer.  Photon mapping "parks" photons in the scene (by essentially casting rays from the light source into the scene), and after that the scene is raytraced.  I honestly think RTRT is the best candidate, because getting a basic raytracer up isn't too difficult, and you can add/cut features as time permits.  With some of the more advanced algorithms (such as the one you linked), they are very complicated and have a high barrier to entry.

Comment: [This made-by-evan example](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/) is a good example of rtrt running in your browser.